# how to put errors in javascript validation

Tags: javascript, validation

i am using a javascript validation with alerts. the full code is :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validateEmail()
{

   var emailID = document.myForm.EMail.value;
   atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
   dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
   if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
   {
       alert("Please enter correct email ID")
       document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
       return false;
   }
   return( true );
}

function validate()
{
   if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your name!" );
     document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.myForm.EMail.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
     document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
     return false;
   }else{
     // Put extra check for data format
     var ret = validateEmail();
     if( ret == false )
     {
          return false;
     }
   }
   if( document.myForm.Zip.value == "" ||
           isNaN( document.myForm.Zip.value ) ||
           document.myForm.Zip.value.length != 5 )
   {
     alert( "Please provide a zip in the format #####." );
     document.myForm.Zip.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.myForm.Country.value == "-1" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your country!" );
     return false;
   }
   return( true );
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi" name="myForm"  onsubmit="return(validate());">
 <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
 <tr>
   <td align="right">Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="right">EMail</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="EMail" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="right">Zip Code</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Zip" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="right">Country</td>
 <td>
 <select name="Country">
   <option value="-1" selected>[choose yours]</option>
   <option value="1">USA</option>
   <option value="2">UK</option>
   <option value="3">INDIA</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="right"></td>
 <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

problem is that i want error divs instead of alerts.how do i append divs with classes of error and success instead of alerts? pls help.

Comment: I don't think you should show an alert when an error occurs. You should throw an `Exception();` and catch it at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to show a better way of showing errors than alert

put a div on the very bottom of your page with `display:none`

Insead of alert just use

```
ShowError('yourmsg');

function ShowError(msg){
setTimeOut(function(){
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML  = msg;
},4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start validating have a single flag such as `blIsFormValid` and keep a single string `var strErrorMsg`

While you are validating the form, if you encounter even a single validation error set `blIsFormValid` to `false`. Next, whenever you face a validation error, write that error into `strErrorMsg`.

For example :

```
function validate()
{
    var  blIsFormValid = true;
    var strErrMsg = '';
    if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
    {
        blIsFormValid = false;
        strErrMsg += "Please enter your name. <br />";       
    }
    if(isEmailValid(document.myForm.Email.value))
    {
        blIsFormValid = false;
        strErrMsg += "Please enter a valid email. <br />";      
    }
    // Add the end checkk...

    is(!blIsFormValid)
    {
        document.getElementById('errDiv').innerHTML = strErrMsg;

    }
    return blIsFormValid;
}
```

At the end check the boolean value of `blIsFormValid` and put it in your error div.

Comment: if name or email both wrong then what it will Print in Div tag.....I think only email error..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using table structure,I think list is good inside the DIV tag....that will be easy to peresent data.......

Now i comming on the point ...use a span tag near to every input box ,Like

```
<tr>
   <td align="right">Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
   <span id="nameError"></span>
</tr>
```

or in java-script define a error on span Id..Like this

```
if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
{
    //   alert( "Please provide your name!" );
    document.getElementById("nameError").innerHTML="Plz provide your name ";
    document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
    return false;
}
```